# Best way to create a dictionary for a later comparison of the elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to code the following issue in python:
I have a multi-column file which I  to store in dictionary/hash in order to compare its element in a further step. The structure of the file look like this:

```
ID  ELEMENT_1   ELEMENT_2   ELEMENT_3   ELEMENT_4   ELEMENT_5
```

where tabs delimit the elements.

Out of this 6 columns I need to store 'ID' and Elements 1, 2, and 3 in a way that the respond to keys and values for each one, so to say: key=id, value= element_1, element_2, elemet_3. Here my idea:

```
sources = open(sys.argv[1], "r").readlines()[32:]
for line in sources:
    tokens = line.split("\t")

    id = tokens[0].strip()
    element_1 = tokens[1].strip()
    element_2 = tokens[2].strip()
    element_3 = tokens[3].strip()

    hash = {}

    hash.setdefault(id, []).append(id)
    hash.setdefault(element_1, []).append(element_1)
    hash.setdefault(element_2, []).append(element_2)
    hash.setdefault(element_3, []).append(element_3)
```

OK, this seems to works, but i think I not following the idea of key and value since they are the same here.
The main idea would be: if two ids are the same in different lines and i.e. element_3 in both lines are different, they should be printed.

```
for line in hash:
        #if duplicates in hash[id] and not the same in element_3:
            print (hash[id], hash[element_1], hash[element_2], hash[element_3])
```

Is this actually possible this way? I am definitely very confused at this point, I hope someone can give some advice.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are duplicate id's?
Overwrite the old one, or add both?

Comment: Not overwrite, add both with the values of each line to a new list or just print them.

Comment: Just print what? The two lines, the id and mismatched elements, or?

Comment: yes, the ids with mismatched elements. The best would be to print id, element_1, element_2, element_3 of the mismatched elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I compare entries as I read them. Meaning that the first occurrence of an entry with a particular `id` will be the one that gets added to the `stored_values` dictionary

`stored_values[id]`  contains an array `[ELEMENT_1,ELEMENT_2,ELEMENT_3,ELEMENT_4,ELEMENT_5]`

```
stored_values = {}
for line in sources:
    # find all the tokens and strip them at the same time
    tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split("\t")]

    new_id, new_values = tokens[0], tokens[1:]

    # check if the id is already stored
    if new_id in stored_values.keys():
        # Evaluate the items in the two lists to see if they are equal
        values_are_equal = True
        for stored_val , new_val in zip(stored_values[new_id], new_values):
            if not stored_val == new_val:
                values_are_equal = False

        if values_are_equal:
            # Do whatever needs to be done if both duplicate id and values
            pass
        if not values_are_equal:
            print("ID '{}', has a duplicate entry with different values".format(new_id))
            print("Stored Entry:  " + str(stored_values[new_id]))
            print("Current Entry: " + str(new_values))
            # Do whatever else needs to be done if duplicate id but different values

    # Finally if this is a new id, then add just add it
    else:
        stored_values[new_id] = new_values
```

**EDIT**: You might also want to add some logic to check that the `new_id` and `new_values` have the proper format/size/type/etc before adding to the stored values list or comparing to an existing list

**EDIT2** The zip function allows you too iterate through multiple lists at the same time

I usually only use the zip function myself when comparing two lists of the same size

If I have two lists

```
lst1 = range(0,10)
lst2 = range(10,20)
```

the loop

```
min_length = min([len(lst1 ), len(lst2 )])
for ii in xrange(min_length ):
    l1 = lst1[ii]
    l2 = lst2[ii]
    # go on to do stuff with l1, l2
```

is practiaclly the same as

```
for l1, l2 in zip(lst1 , lst2 ):
    # go on to do stuff with l1, l2
```

In the solution I assume the lists are the same. ie) `values_are_equal` is `True`.

As I cycle through the lists, if I find that if `stored_val` or `new_val` (which represent values in `stored_values` and `new_values` with matching index) are not the same, then I change the local var `values_are_equal` to `False`.

If I never find a point where `stored_val` or `new_val` are not the same, `values_are_equal` is going to be `True` after the loop

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job if you tweak a little 'new_id' and 'new_values' for my purpose. Just one thing, I'm not really getting the idea how you compare the stored_values with the new_values, may be because I'm not very experienced with the zip-function, could you just go very short into the comparison?

Comment: Sure! I'll add it the solution

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an elegant way to solve the problem.